# Range object does not support assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting a TypeError 'Range' object does not support item assignment. I tried to change the code a little as in add iter(...) before the range, aswell as list(...) before range. However, it didn't help and the Error continues.
Here's the code:

```
def findAnchor(anchors, node):
    start = node                   
    while node != anchors[node]:   
        node = anchors[node]       
    anchors[start] = node          
    return node

def unionFindConnectedComponents(graph):
    anchors = range(len(graph))        
    for node in iter(range(len(graph))):    
        for neighbor in graph[node]:   
            if neighbor < node:        
                continue

            a1 = findAnchor(anchors, node)       
            a2 = findAnchor(anchors, neighbor)   
            if a1 < a2:                          
                anchors[a2] = a1                 
            elif a2 < a1:                        
                anchors[a1] = a2                 

    labels = [None]*len(graph)         
    current_label = 0                  
    for node in range(len(graph)):
        a = findAnchor(anchors, node)  
        if a == node:                  
            labels[a] = current_label  
            current_label += 1         
        else:
            labels[node] = labels[a]   


    return anchors, labels
```

Now the TypeError is in the beginning at anchors[start] = node. And node is a given argument from the second function where it says for node in iter(range(len(graph))). I tried it with iter and with list, neither worked. What to do?

Comment: so closed after all that time, the suggested dupe target was 100% identical... sigh

Answer (score 6):

`anchors = range(len(graph))` generates a `list` in python 2 so you can assign to it.

But in python 3, the behaviour has changed. `range` becomes a lazy sequence generation object, which saves memory & CPU time because it is mostly used to count in loops and its usage to generate a contiguous actual `list` is rather rare.

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

> Rather than being a function, range is actually an immutable sequence type

And such objects don't support slice assignment (`[]` operation)

Quickfix: force iteration on the `range` object, you'll get an object you can use slicing assignment to:

```
anchors = list(range(len(graph)))
```

Comment: Wow amazing, thanks! I kept trying around with the 'node', I thought the error is there because of start = node.

Comment: yes, `for node in iter(range(len(graph))): ` `iter` is useless here.

Comment: gah! Nitpick, but it does *not* become a generator function. It is an immutable, constant-memory, sequence type that support lazy generation of it's values. It is not a generator. It isn't even an iterator. If you don't believe me, try `r = range(10); next(r)`.

Comment: A "range object" is unequivocal terminology. Again, this is all just a nitpick and doesn't detract from your answer really.

Comment: okay but calling `range` a "range object" seems like a cyclic definition to me :)

Comment: But it's not general. It'd be nice to have a name that relates it to other things.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not a specialist, but I know that you can reuse `range` many times, unlike generator functions, so, yes it's not a generator/iterator since it can "rearm" itself.

Comment: ok I pasted the extract from the doc so everyone agrees, thanks :)